# Wordpress save_post hook will be unnecessarily fired

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, gatsby, continuous-deployment

Having a WP multisite as a backend for my blog encountered a really weird issue. The multisite splits the blog into english and german. They have exactly the same setup, plugins, wp-theme etc.

The frontend is a gatsby site (static site generated with react) so have made an action on the `save_post` WP Hook to deploy the site. It worked well until recently it fires really frequently and unreliably but only of the english blog. The german blog as I said has everything the same yet it works as it supposed to work.

The hook makes a request with php curl to the deployHQ endpoint which triggers the deployment. The problem is that the `save_post` hook fires sometimes more than 3 times a minute then stops for maybe one minute then stops for a few minutes then again. Seemingly it does that without any sequence and feels like completely random. The time between 2 such request is never more than 10 minutes.

Do you have any idea what it may causes this or any way of debug?

Thank you for your support in advance!

Comment: `save_post` will also trigger on `autosave` so either disable it or use another hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys it was due to a plugin. Whenever a request was made it fired somehow the post_save hook too. So if you're working with this hook I would recommend **not** to use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-log/